# A question about RSA key generation algorithm

Tags: rsa

I'm fairly new to this stuff so be forgiving. I'm trying to learn how RSA works,
My resources for the manner of sake:

- [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modern-crypt/v/rsa-encryption-part-4)
- [this wikipedia page](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_algorithm#:%7E:text=RSA%20)

This is what I got so far:

since

$m^{phi(n)} \equiv 1 \bmod n$

as long as $m$ coprimes to $n$.

So eventually:

$m^{k * phi(n)+1} \equiv m  \bmod n$

Now we construct $e$ and $d$:

$k*phi(n) +1 = e * d$

$e$ is selected so that it coprimes with $phi(n)$

I have 2 questions:

1. Since $m$  can be anything (this is the encrypted content right?), how do you verify that $m$ and $n$ coprimes, as needed for the Euler's theorom to work?
2. Why do $e$ needs to comprime to $phi(n)$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: 1, RSA can encrypt any messages $m < n$. there are at least two good answers to this. [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1004/18298) 2. How do you find the inverse of $e$? Please search this site before asking? If something is not clear on the answers you can ask.

Comment: As you will see the problem here [How to compute m value from RSA if phi(n) is not relative prime with the e?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/81949/18298) and remember the [correctness requirement](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87815/18298)

Comment: Even the 'simple' version of wikipedia correctly notes you can, and we generally do, use Carmichael's $lambda(pq)=lcm(p-1,q-1)$ instead of Euler's $phi$, but [real wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) is more detailed.