# Cryptographic Systems Involving Modular Exponentiation

Tags: pohlig-hellman-cipher

I am going through an "Introduction to Cryptography" chapter in my Elementary Number Theory course, wherein I'm studying cryptographic systems involving modular exponentiation.

The textbook (By David M. Burton) says that:

> A user who wishes to conceal information might begin by selecting a (large) prime p to serve as the enciphering modulus, and a positive integer 2 < k < p - 2, the enciphering
> exponent. Modulus and exponent, both kept secret, must satisfy gcd(k, p - 1) = 1. The encryption process begins with the conversion of the message to numerical form M by means of a "digital alphabet" in which each letter of the plaintext is replaced
> by a two-digit integer. *It is assumed that the plaintext number M is less than the enciphering modulus p; otherwise, it would be impossible to distinguish M from a larger integer congruent
> to it modulo p.*

Can someone please clarify the last line for me (in italics)? Possibly, by giving an example as to why will it be impossible to distinguish M from a larger integer congruent to it modulo p. What exactly happens when M is greater than p?

Comment: what would be $(k.p + a)^s$ $mod$  $p$ for the key $s$ and message $k.p+a$ where $k$ is an integer?

Comment: A possible duplicate [Uniqueness in modular artihmetic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87811/18298)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone please clarify the last line for me (in italics)?

Ok, here is a very simple example of what can go wrong.

For a very simple example, let us consider $p=11$ (smaller than what they specify, however it'll act the same, and it'll keep the computations simpler), and $k=3$.

Suppose we want to encrypt the message $m=2$; what we'll do to encrypt is compute $m^k \bmod p$, in this case, $2^3 \bmod 11 = 8 \bmod 11 = 8$.  And, later on in the text, they'll explain how to decrypt.

However, to answer your question, suppose we were to try to encrypt the message $m=13$.  In this case, we'd compute $13^3 \bmod 11 = 2197 \bmod 11 = 8$.  That is, we got the exact same ciphertext that we did for $m=2$; that means that if we get the ciphertext $8$, we wouldn't be able to tell whether the original $m$ was $2$ or $13$ (and by default, we assume that it is less than $p$, namely, $m=2$).

It turns out that this encryption method always handles any $m$ the exact same way as $m+p$; hence if we get a message larger than $p$, there will always be a smaller message that encrypts the same way.

As a side note, when I computed $m^k \bmod p$, I wrote it out as $m^k$ and then applied the $\bmod p$ operation.  This works on these small toy examples, but on realistic cases, we convert the $m^k$ into a series of modular multiplications and squarings, and apply the modulo operation after each multiplication/squaring.  This is not related to your question - I'm just trying to anticipate a possible future source of confusion.